# Correct use of Grand Central Dispatch - start, suspend, resume, cancel a thread?

Tags: iphone, ios, multithreading, queue, grand-central-dispatch

i´ve just built a small test project to test Grand Central Dispatch.
I need to use a serial queue. While running the background task, i need to suspend, resume or cancel the thread completely.
And: how do i know if a created queue is already running? (Then i have to restart it).

It´s my first time using multithreading, so therefore it would be really nice to get some hints if i´m using it right. I didn´t find anything like that, so would be cool, if you can check my code. Do i release the objects right? Any further improvements?

Thanks a lot for your help and time.

Here´s the Code or a [link to the sample project](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4870705/Stackoverflow_TestQueue.zip).

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "SVProgressHUD.h"
#import "Queue.h"

@interface ViewController (){
    Queue* queue;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    queue = [[Queue alloc] init];

    UIButton* startbutton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect]; 
    [startbutton setTitle:@"Start Queue" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [startbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(startQueueButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [startbutton setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 200, 100, 70)];
    [self.view addSubview:startbutton];


    UIButton* suspendbutton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect]; 
    [suspendbutton setTitle:@"Stop Queue" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [suspendbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(suspendQueueButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [suspendbutton setFrame:CGRectMake(250, 200, 100, 70)];
    [self.view addSubview:suspendbutton];

    UIButton* resumebutton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect]; 
    [resumebutton setTitle:@"Resume Queue" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [resumebutton addTarget:self action:@selector(resumeQueueButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [resumebutton setFrame:CGRectMake(400, 200, 170, 70)];
    [self.view addSubview:resumebutton];

    UIButton* cancelbutton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect]; 
    [cancelbutton setTitle:@"Cancel Queue" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cancelbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(cancelQueueButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cancelbutton setFrame:CGRectMake(600, 200, 170, 70)];
    [self.view addSubview:cancelbutton];

}

-(void) startQueueButton:(UIButton*) button{    
    NSLog(@"---> startQueueButton");
    [queue start];
}

-(void) suspendQueueButton:(UIButton*) button{
    NSLog(@"---> suspendQueueButton");
    [queue suspend];
}


-(void) resumeQueueButton:(UIButton*) button{
    NSLog(@"---> resumeQueueButton");
    [queue resume];
}

-(void) cancelQueueButton:(UIButton*) button{
    NSLog(@"---> cancelQueueButton");
    [queue cancel];
}



- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Queue.m

```
#import "Queue.h"
#import "SVProgressHUD.h"

@interface Queue (){
    dispatch_queue_t queue;
}

@end

@implementation Queue


-(void) start{
    NSLog(@"Queue - start");    

    int count = 1000;

     // SERIAL QUEUE ======================================
     // =======================================================================

    queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.jf.TestQueue", NULL);

    [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Rendering..."];


    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) 
    {
        dispatch_async(queue, ^{

            NSLog(@"--> ASYNC %d", i);

           // rendering complete, get back to main queue
           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
              {
                 NSLog(@"--> Image rendered: %d", i);

                  if (i == count-1) {
                      NSLog(@"EndRenderingQueue");

                      [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
                  }
              });
        });
    }

    dispatch_release(queue);    // even under ARC we have to release it    
}


-(void) suspend{

    NSLog(@"Queue - suspend");

    if (queue) {
        NSLog(@"___suspend");
        dispatch_suspend(queue);
    }
}

-(void) resume{
    NSLog(@"Queue - resume");
    if (queue) {
        dispatch_resume(queue);
    }
}
-(void) cancel{
    NSLog(@"Queue - cancel");

    if (queue) {
        dispatch_suspend(queue);
        //dispatch_release(queue);  // if it´s uncommented, it crashes. How to release it securely?
        queue = nil;

        [SVProgressHUD dismiss];

    }

}

@end
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe that general practice is that you generally don't suspend background queues unless you absolutely need to (i.e. you have something operating in another queue that can't operate properly/well if your created queue is allowed to run subsequent blocks). There are situations where you might want to do this, but generally you don't have to worry about it. The majority of us are creating queues, using them, letting them sit idle when we're not actively using them (not suspending them, though), continue using it again when we need the background queue again, and when we're all done with them (i.e. we don't need a background queue in the foreseeable future), we release them, at which point we don't use that old queue pointer again.

In terms of how to know if it's suspended, I don't think there's any way, other than `dispatch_debug()`. You're suspending it, so you already know if it's suspended or not, so could write your own wrapper to keep track of your own suspension count. Generally, I would have thought that you would suspend when it was necessary to do so and then resume when the conflicting foreground (or whatever) task was done and when the background queue could safely be used again. In this scenario, determining whether it is suspended or not is more of an academic matter.

Why do you need to suspend your background queue? What business logic problem are you trying to solve? And, by the way, I assume you know that the current block running in that queue is not affected by the suspension. I believe that only queued (either previously queued and waiting, or subsequently queued) blocks are affected, not the current block.

In terms of your code, you're releasing your queue in the start method (e.g., once the queue is emptied, it will be asynchronously deallocated). You should only do that if you don't need the queue any more. If you invoke a `dispatch_release()` (i.e. not using ARC), any future uses of the queue variable would not be reliable (unless, of course, the `dispatch_release()` was done in conjunction with a `dispatch_retain()`). Once you finally release it, you might even want to set the queue variable to nil so you're not tempted to use it. Frankly, I'm surprised that, given that you did a `dispatch_release()` in your start method that you were able to invoke `dispatch_suspend()` and `dispatch_resume()` without some serious exception given that you've already released your queue (unless, by happenstance, the original block of code submitted to that queue had not yet completed).

Bottom line, before you start pursing suspending queues (I'm not sure if you were pursing this out of intellectual curiosity or whether you had some compelling business problem that you're trying to solve), I'd suggest you clarify your question with the business logic and relevant code.

Comment: Wow! Thanks Robert for taking your time to answer my question. I need to use a serial queue, because i have to prerender up to 12+ images. The first image will be shown immediately. All other images will also be rendered in that queue. If the user taps an other button, i want to restart the whole queue from scratch. Therefore i need a way to cancel the current running queue. Do you think i´m right with my logic? Is that possible? Thanks for your help..

Comment: The typical way of canceling an existing block of code is to have some boolean variable that your renderer will check periodically and simply return immediately if it's true.

Comment: By the way, remember that all UI updates should take place on the main queue, so when your background queue is done prerendering one of your twelve images, if you want to update an UIImageView accordingly, make sure you dispatch that little bit of code back to the main queue.

Comment: By the way, I'm presuming that you will not queue up 12+ blocks, but will have one block that does all of your prerendering. That way, it's easy to cancel the rendering if that "cancel" variable is set, and then the next queue block would be for your updated images that need rendering.

Comment: @RobertRyan To me his code above appears to do exactly that - queue up 12+ blocks in com.jf.TestQueue

Comment: @Thompsonian I agree; that's a logical conclusion from his code and comments. I was trying to obtusely suggest that he might want to consider putting the prerendering of the associated 12+ images in a single block, as I suspect that it might be easier to cancel that in one fell swoop (especially given that dispatch queues don't handle canceling blocks as well as I suspect operation queues might).

Comment: @RobertRyan Agreed - and I'll reiterate your suggestion to dispatch any UI uodates back to the main thread as they are completed.